# Reverse number _order_ from a scanner input recursively

Tags: java, recursion, java.util.scanner

I'm having trouble trying to solve a recursive assignment and have had no success.

The goal of the assignment is to call function

```
reverseNumbers(new Scanner("11 23 31 49 56 611"))
```

and get the output

```
"611 56 49 31 23 11"
```

while not being allowed to use arrays, lists, strings and the method should only declare one variable.

The code that I have written does not work. I'm getting a `StackOverflow` error, which I understand why I am getting. It is because the parameter `scan` doesn't change and it has to for the recursion to work. However, I do not know how to alter the input argument with the tools available in the `Scanner` utility.

```
public static String reverseNumbers(Scanner scan){
   if (!scan.hasNext()) {
      return "";
   }
   else {
      return reverseNumbers(scan)  + " " + scan.nextInt();
   }
}
```

Comment: Homework question with an attempt to solve it and description of problem OP is facing. That is rare sight. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are recursing before you read the number from the scanner.

Remember that Java [evaluates operands left-to-right](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7). So, it evaluates `reverseNumbers(scan)` before `scan.nextInt()`.

This means that it will keep on:

- Seeing that `scan.hasNext()`
- Calling `reverseNumbers`
- Seeing that `scan.hasNext()`
- Calling `reverseNumbers`
- Seeing that `scan.hasNext()`
- Calling `reverseNumbers`
- ...

Evaluate `scan.hasNext()` before you make the recursive call:

```
int next = scan.nextInt();
return reverseNumbers(scan) + " " + next;
```

Now, you're consuming the value that you're detecting with `hasNext()` (which should be `hasNextInt()`, by the way; or use `String next = scan.next()`), so the value you detected the scanner "has" won't be detected again.